# Using passphrase callback in ruby gpgme

Tags: ruby, gnupg, gpgme

I am using ruby gpgme gem (1.0.8). My passphrase callback isn't called:

```
def passfunc(*args)
  fd = args.last
  io = IO.for_fd(fd, 'w')
  io.puts "mypassphrase"
  io.flush
end

opts = {
  :passphrase_callback => method(:passfunc)
}
GPGME.decrypt(input,output, opts)
```

Does someone have working example of passphrase callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample of callback you can find in the following working example. It signs a file in detached mode, i.e., the signature file is separated from the original file. It uses the default keyring at ~/.gnupg or something like that. To use a different directory for your keyring, set the environment variable ENV["GNUPGHOME"]="" before call GPGME::sign().

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'gpgme'

puts "Signing #{ARGV[0]}" 
input = File.open(ARGV[0],'r')

PASSWD = "abc"

def passfunc(hook, uid_hint, passphrase_info, prev_was_bad, fd)
    puts("Passphrase for #{uid_hint}: ")
    io = IO.for_fd(fd, 'w')
    io.write(PASSWD+"\n")
    io.flush
end

output = File.open(ARGV[0]+'.asc','w')

sign = GPGME::sign(input, {
        :passphrase_callback => method(:passfunc), 
        :mode => GPGME::SIG_MODE_DETACH
    })
output.write(sign)
output.close
input.close
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another working example for you that doesn't use a detached signature. To test this, simply change 'user@host.name' to the identifier of your key and do this: GPG.decrypt(GPG.encrypt('some text', :armor => true))

```
require 'gpgme'
require 'highline/import'

module GPG
  ENCRYPT_KEY = 'user@host.com'
  @gpg = GPGME::Crypto.new

  class << self

    def decrypt(encrypted_data, options = {})
      options = { :passphrase_callback => self.method(:passfunc) }.merge(options)
      @gpg.decrypt(encrypted_data, options).read 
    end

    def encrypt(data_to_encrypt, options = {})
      options = { :passphrase_callback => self.method(:passfunc), :armor => true }.merge(options)
      @gpg.encrypt(data_to_encrypt, options).read
    end

    private
      def get_passphrase
        ask("Enter passphrase for #{ENCRYPT_KEY}: ") { |q| q.echo = '*' }
      end

      def passfunc(hook, uid_hint, passphrase_info, prev_was_bad, fd)
        begin
          system('stty -echo')
          io = IO.for_fd(fd, 'w')
          io.puts(get_passphrase)
          io.flush
        ensure
          (0 ... $_.length).each do |i| $_[i] = ?0 end if $_
          system('stty echo')
        end
        $stderr.puts
      end
  end
end
```

Cheers!,

--
Carl

Answer (score 2):

It is important to note that as of GnuPG 2.0 (and in 1.4 when the `use-agent` option is used) `pinentry` is used for passphrase collection. This means that the gpgme passphrase callback will [not be invoked](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2011-February/040645.html). This is described [here](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-devel/2013-February/027345.html) and an example of usage can be found in the `gpgme-tool` [example](http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gpgme.git;a=blob;f=src/gpgme-tool.c;h=d42179bde67e9ef80296d6f39db5f541e22519e1;hb=HEAD#l1795).