# GPGME Passphrase prompt issue (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gnupg, openpgp

In the example below, I have tried password and passphrase. Neither seem to allow me to run my code without a openpgp box prompting for the passphrase, the following message:

Pinentry Mac
"Please enter the passphrase to unlock the secret key for the OpenPGP certificate"

What do I need to change to allow my code to run without the prompt? I know my password is correct in the code.

I have tried :

```
ctx = GPGME::Ctx.new :password=> 'password'
```

and this:

```
ctx = GPGME::Ctx.new :passphrase_callback => method(:passfunc)
```

But both do not seem to work. Any advice is appreciated.

```
  def self.passfunc(obj, uid_hint, passphrase_info, prev_was_bad, fd)
    io = IO.for_fd(fd, 'w')
    io.puts 'password'
    io.flush
  end

  def self.decrypt_file(local_file, decrypted_file = nil)
    # Set decrypted file path if one is not provided
    decrypted_file = local_file.chomp(File.extname(local_file)) + ".csv" if decrypted_file == nil
    encrypted_data = GPGME::Data.new(File.open(local_file))

    # Set the password and GPG Key to decryption
    ctx = GPGME::Ctx.new :password=> 'password'

    # I have tried the passphrase call back
    #ctx = GPGME::Ctx.new :passphrase_callback => method(:passfunc)

    #KEY= GPGME::Data.new(File.open("key.gpg"))
    ctx.import_keys Rebal::Config::KEY

    # Decrypt the data
    decrypted = ctx.decrypt encrypted_data
    decrypted.seek(0)

    #Write the data to a file
    File.write(decrypted_file, decrypted.read)

    #return path
    decrypted_file
  end
```

The following link did not seem to help...
[Using passphrase callback in ruby gpgme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867757/using-passphrase-callback-in-ruby-gpgme)
and I'm not sure what this link is referring to or how it addresses my specific issue, but it might be the soltuion...
[how to bypass pinentry (passphrase screen) while decrypting a file using gpgme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671099/how-to-bypass-pinentry-passphrase-screen-while-decrypting-a-file-using-gpgme)  If someone can explain to me what changes to my code would help, I'm listening.

SOLUTION: I found out that the pinentry prompt is because of GPG2 vs GPG1.4. I downgraded to GPG1.4 and now it seems to work.

If someone knows how to get GPG2 to work, please comment

thank you

Comment: Since you found the solution, would you mind writing it up as an Answer? There's nothing wrong with Answering your own Question.

Answer (score 4):

Providing `pinentry_mode: GPGME::PINENTRY_MODE_LOOPBACK` option worked for me on GPG2:

```
GPGME::Ctx.new(
  pinentry_mode: GPGME::PINENTRY_MODE_LOOPBACK,
  passphrase_callback: method(:passfunc)
)
```